Applying Theorem to verify the logical equivalences, trying to verify if this is correct no answer in the book
Simplify:
$(p~\land~(\lnot(\lnot~p \lor q)))~\lor~(p~\land~q)~\equiv~p$
A: $(p~\land~(\lnot(\lnot~p \lor q)))$
B: $(p~\land~q)$

A:

$(p~\land~(\lnot(\lnot~p \lor q)))~\equiv~(p~\land~(\lnot\lnot~p \land~\lnot~q))~(1)$
$(p~\land~(\lnot\lnot~p \land~\lnot~q))~\equiv~(p~\land~(p \land \lnot q))~(2)$
$(p~\land~(p \land \lnot q))~\equiv~(p~\land~p) \land \lnot q~(3)$
$(p~\land~p) \land \lnot q~\equiv~p~\land \lnot q~(4)$

Then:

$p~\land \lnot q~\lor~(p~\land~q)~\equiv~p~(5)$
$(p~\land \lnot q)~\lor~(p~\land~q)~\equiv~p~\land~(\lnot q~\lor~q)~(6)$
$p~\land~(\lnot q~\lor~q)~\equiv~p~\land~(q~\lor\lnot q)~(7)$
$p~\land~(q~\lor \lnot q)~\equiv~p~\land~t~(8)$
$p~\land~t~\equiv~p~(9)$


Laws applied from top to bottom:
(1) By de Morgan for $\lor$
(2) By Double negative $\lnot~\lnot$
(3) By Associative for $\land$
(4) By Idempotent for $\land$
(6) By Distributive for $\land and two \lor$
(7) By Commutative for $\lor$
(8) By Negative $\lor$
(9) By Identity for $\land$
My Solution to a problem in the book, however, problem 2.1.54 does not have a solution in the back side. So, I thought, asking here to verify.
   Discrete Mathematics with Applications 5th Edition
   by Susanna S. Epp


Yes, all good!
Just make sure to add some parentheses on line 1 after the Then:

$\color{red}(p~\land \lnot q\color{red})~\lor~(p~\land~q)~\equiv~p~(5)$

It's smart to split things up the way you do, but when you plug the result of simplifying a component statement back into the larger statement be aware that you probably need to add some parentheses.

Hahaha yes, I did that on my paper here, but forgot to add them here. ;-)
